# Conditionally show a view controller on UITabBar selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Context: When tapping my "User" tab bar item, I want to check if a user is logged in. If so, I want to show my "Profile" view, and if not, I want to show my "Log in" view. How should I go about doing this? I have tried subclassing `UITabBarController` and putting my logic in the `prepareForSegue` function, but to no avail.

Essentially, how can I select which view controller I would like to push when selecting a tab bar item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is this delegate method of `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

```
optional func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
```

Document

> Return Value
>
> YES if the view controller’s tab should be selected or NO if the current tab should remain active.
>
> Discussion
>
> The tab bar controller calls this method in response to the user tapping a tab bar item. You can use this method to dynamically decide whether a given tab should be made the active tab.